# Redirecting webapps in nginx content folders

Tags: nginx, wordpress, centos6

I have setup an nginx + php + wordpress site at **www.example.com**
When I go to example.com on my browseer I see my wordpress blog as I expect and can work with it flawlessly, no problem there.
But now I wanted to keep using nginx for other webapps without losing the blog.

Ningx content root is at `/srv/www/html`
Wordpress root is at `/srv/www/wordpress/public_html`

I wanted to for example create /srv/www/newsite and drop some webapp in there and be able to access it through example.com/newsite, is that possible?

I tried creating the equivalent in sites-available with the following content:

```
server {
    server_name example.com/newsite www.example.com/newsite;
    access_log /srv/www/newsite/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/newsite/logs/error.log;
    root /srv/www/newsite;
```

but it gives me a wordpress page-not-found.

Just to be clear, I want to keep wordpress the way it is now, I want example.com to show me worpdress by default. I just want example.com/newsite to be able to serve its own files.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring a separate server block, within your example.com server block for wordpress, you can open a new location block, like so:

```
location ~ /newsite/ {
  root /srv/www/;
}
```

Comment: you mean to modify the sites-available file for wordpress? I think that would be against good practices. This wouldnt be an app related to worpress but something completely unrelated.

Comment: I'm referring to the nginx configuration file for your domain example.com. The fact that it's wordpress is less relevant than the fact that it's what is managing the domain. Nginx doesn't support URL's in the `server_name` directive, and you can only have one `server {}` code block per `server_name`.

Comment: I tried your advice but same issue remains. I added the new location block on the wordpress config file for nginx. Whe I try to access newsite it still shows me the 404 of wordpress.

Comment: Have you tried moving up the location block higher in the wordpress configuration? What errors are provided in the error log? On CentOS it's located at: /var/log/nginx/error_log